# Django forms.VaildationError not showing on a class based view

Tags: python, django

My forms.validationerror is not showing. Below is my form that I am using. The if statement works and it detects the issue, and prints out the content successfully. As a lot the existing errors on stackoverflow suggest, the content is not None as shown in the print statement.

```
            class PollItemMessageAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
                class Meta:
                    model = Message
                    fields = [
                        "content"
                    ]

                    labels = {
                        'content': 'Add your comment',
                    }

                    widgets = {
                        'content': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 10, 'rows': 5}),
                    }


                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

                    # this line should be before a super call
                    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)

                    super(PollItemMessageAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                    self.helper = FormHelper()
                    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
                    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', value='Post', css_class='buttonspace btn-success'))


                def clean_content(self):
                    content = self.cleaned_data.get("content")

                    if len(content) > 50:
                        print content
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Please limit your message to less the 50 characters")

                    return content
```

Below is my views.py post statement in my class based view, which skips the form.isvalid to be redirected to the same url where the error message should appear. I am using a detailview and formmixin in my class based view if it helps. I cant see where the issue is coming from in the absence of a traceback. Any help would be appreciated.

```
                def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                    url = "/polls/" + str(self.get_object().id)

                    form = self.get_form()
                    if request.method == "POST":

                        if form.is_valid():

                            print "works"

                            return self.form_valid(form)

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: are you sure you are passing more than 50 strings???

Comment: I am counting the number of characters in my string by using len(content).

Comment: your row and column multiplies to 5*10 = 50, so in the textarea you are not even passing more than 50 characters, so how will the error raise, try check len > 10 and check

Comment: I tried len >10, if I put in "dude hello man" it doesnt go through, if I put in "dude hello" it goes through(count is 10), I dont think the len is measuring the the row and column, it is measuring the length of the string.

Comment: yeah so thats working, you were not passing more than 50 characters thus no error was raised

Comment: No, its not working still, the validation error is not showing, if I pass more then 50 characters. The issue is because my validation error is not popping up when I put in more then 50 characters. My problem is that this line is not stopping the user - raise forms.ValidationError("Please limit your message to less the 50 characters")

Comment: You should not be overriding `post` here; generally it is a bad idea to override get and post in class-based views. The only thing you need to define is the redirect URL, which can be done in `get_success_url()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @DanielRoseman I understand what you mean, now I dont successfully post the data and redirect back to itself, all my context now ends up empty after I get a form_invalid. But if I dont override post I will run into the issue of method not allowed (POST) when I do the form submission.

Comment: What view are you inheriting from? You need to use some kind of form view.

Comment: I was inheriting from detailview and formmixin, I just tried formview now and it completely works for both the submission and the error validation. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here if the form is not valid, you have to return like this:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {'errors': form.errors, 'form':form})
```

and display the errors in the template or `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` inside the template will show the error.